# Tensorflow CNN only 1 output predict value

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I've already looked into similar topics but none of the tips helped me. My model predicts and outputs only 1 class, even in the console I see only 1 array value. I have to check if the font in the account number is fake or real. It prints an accuracy of 0.99 even 1.00 but after manually checking it with model.predicts it only outputs 0's. I train it on 1000 pictures of each class. Any solutions? My code:

```
train = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
    validation = train_set = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255)
    validation_set = validation.flow_from_directory('Samples', class_mode='binary', batch_size=30, target_size=(500, 50), shuffle=True, seed=42, color_mode='rgb')
    train_set = train.flow_from_directory(directory='Train', class_mode='binary', batch_size=30, target_size=(500, 50), shuffle=True, seed=42, color_mode='rgb')
    print(train_set.classes)
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(500, 50, 3)),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size = (2, 2)),
        tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    print(train_set.class_indices)
    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics= ['accuracy'])
    model.fit(train_set, epochs=2, validation_data=validation_set)

    path = 'Samples/'
    DIRECTORIES = ['Fake', 'Real']
    for dir in DIRECTORIES:
        for file in os.listdir(path+dir):
            img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(path+dir+'/'+file)
            img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)
            img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
            images = np.vstack([img])
            val = np.argmax(model.predict(images))
            print(val)
```

Photos to compare:
[Real](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E84Wv.png)
[Fake](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW8XU.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XGd2B.png)

Comment: argmax is wrong, it should be -> (model.predict(images) > 0.5)

Answer (score 1):

You're using your model as if you had two output neurons in your output layer. `np.argmax(model.predict(images))` would return the index of the neuron with the maximum value, but since you only have 1, it will always return 0. Just check if the value returned by `predict` exceeds the threshhold or alternativly use two neurons.

Comment: could you help me how to use 2 predicting neurons? i'd like to have values like
0.4 for 1 class 0.6 for 2nd class